# horizontal align absolute and static elements using css and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

- Trying to align absolute and static element using css and jquery
- Render static element using css
- Render absolute element using css
- Reset the "top" value for absolute element using jquery. I use same margins/padding etc as was configured for static element in css
- But my absolute element and static element does not get aligned horizontally.
- Also, on browser resize, the layout is even more distorted

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/bG537/30/

Please try browser resize and then reload browser to see difference

How can I align the two abs/static elements using css and jquery???

HTML

```
<div class="space">
</div>
<div class="rel_class">
    STATIC
</div>
<div class="abs_class">
    ABS
</div>
```

CSS

```
.space {
    margin-top:80px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.rel_class {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-left:120px;
    margin-top:9%;
    border:1px solid blue;
}

.abs_class {
    position: absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

jquery

```
$(function() {
    var abs_ele = $(".abs_class");
    var tp = 80 + 0.09*($(window).height());
    abs_ele.css({top:tp+'px'});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I have updated your code. Please check below link.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bG537/36/

Comment: thx much...would you point me to the issue in what I have done....logically it sld have worked....just pointers....thx a ton!!!!

Comment: I have taken top position of your static div at two time. First when page load and second, when browser resize, then simply given that top position to absolute div.